# ExtJS change label value

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

I'm trying to show the current date and time using this:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

and then the code below to update my label, which did not work:

```
var controller = this;
var refs = controller.getReferences();

refs.dateLabelId.text.setValue = currentDate;
```

dateLabelId is the reference of my label

---

PROBLEM SOLVED

```
refs.dateLabelId.label.setText(currentDate)
```

Comment: Ext JS 5.1.x @qmat

Comment: instead of setValue, did u try with text.value?

Comment: yes, no result @Saloo

Comment: Can you post you label config code? Because if you are using label, then you can set it using label.setText('text') method

Comment: i edited my post @Saloo

Comment: you are correct, label.setText(currentDate) is working but page is not loading, i can see the change on F12 mode. Is page not loading because of the time always update? have you got an idea ? @Saloo

Comment: What error you are getting? I don't think its because of time update.

Comment: okey that was a loading time error but i fixed it, i created another event for label and run codes from there so its ok now, thank you @Saloo

Comment: please post the answer as an official answer and accept it, thx

Comment: I posted but 'You can accept your own answer in 2 days'. I'm new here so ty for edits @Creos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is solved with:

```
refs.dateLabelId.label.setText(currentDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also update field label like this :

refs.dateLabelId.setFieldLabel(currentDate);